# C# Bool Variable always false

Tags: c#, variables, boolean

I am comparing two strings:

```
bool d = 
    (String.Equals(ethernetHeader.Source,staticForm.textBox1.Text.ToString()));
```

this statement is always false even in console both are same as below..

> ethernetHeader.Source=00:25:64:4F:21:D9
>
> textBox1.Text=00:25:64:4F:21:D9

any possible reason??

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Trim` in order to have no spaces on lead or end of your string.

```
Boolean d = ethernetHeader.Source.Trim() == staticForm.textBox1.Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an override with StringComparison.

> When you call a string comparison method such as String.Compare,
>   String.Equals, or String.IndexOf, you should always call an overload
>   that includes a parameter of type StringComparison so that you can
>   specify the type of comparison that the method performs. For more
>   information, see Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET
>   Framework.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
bool d = 
    (String.Equals(ethernetHeader.Source, staticForm.textBox1.Text.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```